# Correct regex not working in grep

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have this regex:

```
(?<=prefix).*$
```

which returns any character following string "prefix" and it works fine on any online regex engines (e.g. https://regex101.com). The problem is when I use that regex in bash:

```
grep '(?<=prefix).*$' <<< prefixSTRING
```

it does not match anything. Why that regex does not work with grep?

Comment: This really highlights why regex101 needs a POSIX flavor selector the way it does for JS, Perl/PHP, and Python. I can't count the number of times I've wished for that.

Comment: Related: [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119905/170373)

Comment: Also, the `.*$` matches any string up to the end-of-line (or end-of-string), not just any one character.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You seem to have defined the right regex, but not set the sufficient flags in command-line for `grep` to understand it. Because by default `grep` supports BRE and with `-E` flag it does ERE. What you have (look-aheads) are available only in the PCRE regex flavor which is supported only in GNU `grep` with its `-P` flag.

Assuming you need to extract *only* the matching string after `prefix` you need to add an extra flag `-o` to let know `grep` that print *only* the matching portion as

```
grep -oP '(?<=prefix).*$' <<< prefixSTRING
```

There is also a version of `grep` that supports PCRE libraries by default - [`pcregrep`](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcre.html#SEC2) in which you can just do

```
pcregrep -o '(?<=prefix).*$' <<< prefixSTRING
```

Detailed explanation on various regex flavors are explained in this wonderful [Giles' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119906/112235) and tools that implement each of them

Answer (score 40):

Regular expressions come in many different flavours.  What you are showing is a Perl-like regular expression (PCRE, "Perl Compatible Regular Expression").

`grep` does POSIX regular expressions.  These are [basic regular expressions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) (BRE) and [extended regular expressions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) (ERE, if `grep` is used with the  `-E` option).  See the manual for `re_format` or `regex` or whatever similar manual your `grep` manual refers to on your system, or the POSIX standard texts that I just linked to.

If you use GNU `grep`, you would be able to use Perl-like regular expressions if you used `grep` with the GNU `grep`-specific `-P` option.

Also note that `grep` returns *lines* by default, not substrings from lines.  Again, with GNU `grep` (and some other `grep` implementations), you may use the `-o` option to get only the bit(s) that matches the given expression from each line.

Note that both `-P` and `-o` are non-standard extensions [the POSIX specification of `grep`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/grep.html).

If you are not using GNU `grep`, then you may use `sed` instead to get the bit between the string `prefix` and the end of the line:

```
sed -n 's/.*prefix\(.*\)/\1/p' file
```

What this does is to only print the lines that `sed` manages to apply the given substitution to.  The substitution will replace the whole line that matches the expression (which is a BRE), with the piece of it that occurs after the string `prefix`.

Note that if there are several instances of `prefix` on a line, the `sed` variation would return the string after the *last* one, while the GNU `grep` variation would return the string after the *first* one (which would include the other instances of `prefix`).

The `sed` solution would be portable to all Unix-like systems.

Answer (score 6):

As the other answers have stated, `grep` does not use a regex flavour with lookbehinds (by default with GNU `grep`, or not at all with other versions).

If you find yourself unable to use GNU `grep` or `pcregrep`, you can use `perl` if you have it.

The command line equivalent with `perl` would be:

```
perl -ne 'print if /(?<=prefix).*$/' <<< prefixSTRING
```

You put the desired regex between the slashes. As you are using Perl, this uses [Perl's regex flavour](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Comment: or `print "$&\n" if ...` if they want to output only the part after the `prefix`